# Creating additional array based on datetime intervals

Tags: javascript

React is not my main language, so I apologize in advance if the code is not technically correct. I am just trying to write as I think it should be.

Anyways, I have an array that consists of an time interval divided into quarters, i.e. an interval from 8 to and including 11 would look something like this:

```
const timeInterval = [8:00, 8:15, 8:30, 8:45, 9:00, 9:15, 9:30, 9:45, 10:00, 10:15, 10:30, 10:45, 11:00, 11:15, 11:30, 11:45]
```

On the other hand I have an array of lists that consists of a datetime intervals within this main `timeInterval`, e.g.:

```
const subsetTimeIntervals = [[8:30, 8:45, 9:00, 9:15, 9:30], [10:45, 11:00, 11:15]]
```

What I would like returned to me is some how a new list/array that consists of 1's and 0's depending on whether the time is in the `timeInterval` list. So I need some kind of matching I think (which I am not familiar with in React). So basically the output should be a list with the same length as `timeInterval` that looks something like:

```
const finalList = [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0]
```

Maybe even a dictionary such as:

```
const finalDict = {8:00: 0, 8:15: 0, 8:30: 1, 8:45: 1, 9:00: 1, 9:15:1, 9:30: 0, 9:45: 0, 10:00: 0, 10:15: 0, 10:30: 0, 10:45: 1, 11:00: 1, 11:15: 1, 11:30: 0, 11:45: 0}
```

How can this be achieved ?

EDIT:

After having a look around I actually found what I think might be close to a solution, i.e.:

```
const listItems = timeInterval.map((time) =>
if (time in flatten(subsetTimeIntervals)) {
    <ListItem key=time value=1 />
} else {
    <ListItem key=time value=0 />
);
```

So my issue here is the `in flatten(subsetTimeIntervals)` which I am not sure how works in JS ? I would think the list of lists should be flattened, and then just checking whether each item in `timeInterval` is in that flattened list. So I guess I basically only need this part to achieve my goal?

Comment: React is not a language, is a framework. Your tag is wrong. I will change into `javascript`

Comment: Also, the values in your arrays should be string: "8:00", "8:15", "8:30" ...

Comment: Yeah, maybe it should be strings, however, in my case I am actually converting it to datetime with the date-fns package, so I guess it's more of an object than a string, when actually converting from a string to a datetime object. But yeah, you are probably correct :)

Comment: @GiovanniEsposito It's still React, so you shouldn't have removed that tag.

Comment: @DenverDang answering to your question in EDIT: as I wrote in my answer, your `if (time in flatten(subsetTimeIntervals))` should be `if (subsetTimeIntervals.flat(1).includes(time))` and yes, you only need this part to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One `forEach` and a condition to fill array of 0's and 1's:

```js
const timeInterval = ["8:00", "8:15", "8:30", "8:45", "9:00", "9:15", "9:30", "9:45", "10:00", "10:15", "10:30", "10:45", "11:00", "11:15", "11:30", "11:45"];

const subsetTimeIntervals = [["8:30", "8:45", "9:00", "9:15", "9:30"], ["10:45", "11:00", "11:15"]];

let result = [];

timeInterval.forEach(time => {
  if (subsetTimeIntervals.flat(1).includes(time)) result.push(1);
  else result.push(0);
})

console.log(result);
```

Note: I used `flat(1)` to create 1 array from `subsetTimeIntervals` arrays.

Answer (score 0):

`Array.map` with `Array.some` will do the trick.

`Array.map` will return a new node depending on each value from `timeInterval` array.

`Array.some` will check the node from `timeInterval` is present in `subsetTimeIntervals`

**Working Fiddle**

```js
const timeInterval = ['8:00', '8:15', '8:30', '8:45', '9:00', '9:15', '9:30', '9:45', '10:00', '10:15', '10:30', '10:45', '11:00', '11:15', '11:30', '11:45'];
const subsetTimeIntervals = [['8:30', '8:45', '9:00', '9:15', '9:30'], ['10:45', '11:00', '11:15']];
const finalList = timeInterval.map((node) => subsetTimeIntervals.some(item => item.indexOf(node) > -1) ? 1 : 0);
console.log(finalList)
```